# Location Listener in Background Service Android

Tags: java, android, implementation, locationlistener

Which is the better approach, directly implementing `LocationListener` like this

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service implements LocationListener {}
```

or normally declared the `LocationListener` inside the class?

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the second piece of code you have to call the attribute `locationListener`prior to calling the methods of the interface.

In the first piece of code you can access the interface methods directly.

So if you know that every method call costs cpu time then to implement it directly in the class rather than putting it as an attribute would be beneficial.

In this case you have 1 reference to `BackgroundService` with which you can access methods of LocationListener

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service implements LocationListener {}
```

In this case you have 2 references, one to *BackgroundService* and another to *locationListener*

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {};
}
```

But then again, if your program doesnt have critical time limits, it doesnt really matter.
Above all its important that your code is readable.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank's ,For your answer thats really Help me .. Well Explained :)