# Background service with location listener in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I am creating a background service that will run in its own process.  It should allow me to listen if the device location has changed. I should be able to change criteria like the distance moved before notifying the UI.

How can I do the same? I have a little knowledge of service and `LocationListener` implementations. Any tutorials around the net would be appreciated.

I got one [back-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227446/location-listener-in-background-service-android) from stack overflow, but I didn't understand much of it.

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: See latest GoogleApiClient method http://stackoverflow.com/a/41981246/3496570

Answer (score 13):

I know I am posting this answer little late, but I felt it is worth using Google's fuse location provider service to get the current location.

Main features of this api are :

**1.Simple APIs:** Lets you choose your accuracy level as well as power consumption.

**2.Immediately available:** Gives your apps immediate access to the best, most recent location.

**3.Power-efficiency:** It chooses the most efficient way to get the location with less power consumptions

**4.Versatility:** Meets a wide range of needs, from foreground uses that need highly accurate location to background uses that need periodic location updates with negligible power impact.

It is flexible in while updating in location also.
If you want current location only when your app starts then you can use `getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient)` method.

If you want to update your location continuously then you can use `requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest, LocationListener)`

You can find a very nice blog about fuse location [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/) and google doc for fuse location also can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).

**Update**

According to developer docs starting from Android O they have added new limits on background location.

> If your app is running in the background, the location system service
>   computes a new location for your app only a few times each hour. This
>   is the case even when your app is requesting more frequent location
>   updates.
>   However if your app is running in the foreground, there is no change in
>   location sampling rates compared to Android 7.1.1 (API level 25).

Comment: I think you are right, but some Custom Rom removed google play service so you can not use the fuse location provider.

Comment: If you just want to know roughly where you are at a certain time or for less accurate tracking then `FusedLocationProvider` is ok but for apps that require high accuracy tracking it's just not good enough

Comment: A solution for those Custom Roms, is to use [LOST](https://github.com/mapzen/LOST) from Mapzen. Offers same functionalities with FusedLocationProviderAPI from Google, without the need to register with Google Play Service

Comment: How can I track user route in a running app in android Oreo if it can update location only few times each hour?

Answer (score 8):

Background location service. It will be restarted even after killing the app.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Button stop;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (alarmManager == null) {
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000,
                    pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**BookingTrackingService.java**

```
public class BookingTrackingService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "BookingTrackingService";
    private Context context;
    boolean isGPSEnable = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
    double latitude, longitude;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    long notify_interval = 30000;

    public double track_lat = 0.0;
    public double track_lng = 0.0;
    public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
    Intent intent;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5, notify_interval);
        intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        this.context = this;


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy <<");
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    private void trackLocation() {
        Log.e(TAG, "trackLocation");
        String TAG_TRACK_LOCATION = "trackLocation";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("latitude", "" + track_lat);
        params.put("longitude", "" + track_lng);

        Log.e(TAG, "param_track_location >> " + params.toString());

        stopSelf();
        mTimer.cancel();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    /******************************/

    private void fn_getlocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CAN'T GET LOCATION");
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            if (isNetworkEnable) {
                location = null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "isNetworkEnable latitude" + location.getLatitude() + "\nlongitude" + location.getLongitude() + "");
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        track_lat = latitude;
                        track_lng = longitude;
//                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isGPSEnable) {
                location = null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "isGPSEnable latitude" + location.getLatitude() + "\nlongitude" + location.getLongitude() + "");
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        track_lat = latitude;
                        track_lng = longitude;
//                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "START SERVICE");
            trackLocation();

        }
    }

    private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fn_getlocation();
                }
            });

        }
    }

//    private void fn_update(Location location) {
//
//        intent.putExtra("latutide", location.getLatitude() + "");
//        intent.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
//        sendBroadcast(intent);
//    }
}
```

**AlarmReceive.java (BroadcastReceiver)**

```
public class AlarmReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Service_call_"  , "You are in AlarmReceive class.");
        Intent background = new Intent(context, BookingTrackingService.class);
//        Intent background = new Intent(context, GoogleService.class);
        Log.e("AlarmReceive ","testing called broadcast called");
        context.startService(background);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <service
            android:name=".ServiceAndBroadcast.BookingTrackingService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".ServiceAndBroadcast.AlarmReceive"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: `if (isNetworkEnable) {` it could be `if (!isNetworkEnable) {` missing NOT in else case. ;)

Comment: Also, need to check permission availability. `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { return;}`

Comment: I was able to fetch location when app was running using this code , but when app was killed it did not work , i'm trying to update location of user in database even when app is killed

Comment: @MandeepKumar which device are you using. i also facing some issue related with device. but i very well working with Nexus and Samsung phone

Comment: I was able to develop a project where I can fetch the location on of user even if app is killed , it was some work around , but it worked , my mail - mandeepsangwan21@gmail.com if you need the project.

Comment: why you write 'stopSelf()' ?? by this code service run just once.

Comment: In new Android versions, tons of permissions are required for location service to keep running. This simple service wont work, i m pretty sure

Comment: Agree with @M.UsmanKhan becauase in latest Android versions `startService ` is never going to keep app in background state. All Stuff needed to use foreground service and keep app running throught this. For more details - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

Answer (score 2):

Very easy no need create class extends LocationListener
1- Variable

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private LocationListener mLocationListener;
private static double currentLat =0;
private static double currentLon =0;
```

2- onStartService()

```
@Override public void onStartService() {
    addListenerLocation();
}
```

3- Method addListenerLocation()

```
 private void addListenerLocation() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            currentLat = location.getLatitude();
            currentLon = location.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),currentLat+"-"+currentLon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Location lastKnownLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if(lastKnownLocation!=null){
                currentLat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                currentLon = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 10, mLocationListener);
}
```

4- onDestroy()

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
}
```

Comment: For some reason the location updates only happen when app is in view...