# How to make Geo Fencing without using google play Service (Android)

Tags: android, geofencing

I'm looking to get notifications when you enter or leave an area. I DO NOT want to use google play services.

Is it just a matter of setting up an alarm service, then call a background service to the GEO part?

I can't find any good examples to how to "run a service" in android, wake up on a set interval and then check GEO location. I have seen all the examples on how to use the GEO fencing built in to Google Play Services but again, for a variety of reasons I do NOT want to use the Google Play Service.

Does anyone know of any good examples or links?

Comment: Did you have a look at the corresponding [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)?

Comment: I have but, it's not really an example :( I've got some this in use in an "app" but, when my app is closed, I no longer seem to get updates. I was hoping for an example rather than a doc. But, thanks this is a great resource.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) which will receive the location updates while your application is not active.

Comment: agreed... looking for an example of that ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478179/background-service-with-location-listener-in-android ?