# Send latitude and longitude to server every 5 minutes even the app was closed

Tags: android, google-maps, background

I need to send latitude and longitude values to the server for every 5 minutes.Our team members can be close this application during the travels that time also latitude and longitude value send to the server.I didn't have idea to how to implement this method.

Comment: create background services fetch location and send it to server simple!

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar This is first time I am working with background process.I haven't enough knowledge in this area.I know get the latitude and longitude but how send the data to server when app was in close.

Comment: lets made easy for you. first learn about background services https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services , then how get location from device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android and http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/location/display-address.html in last send on server(i think this you already know)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar thank you...

Comment: some stack answer please check but before use it learn abut them from previous comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/28535885/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14478179/1168654

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found an answer for my question. We can run the background process many methods like Intent Service and Alarm Manager. I used the Alarm Manager for Background Process.It will call service every 5 minutes.In my `MainActivity`,I put the below mentioned Code.

```
    private void scheduleNotify()
    {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SendLocation.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,0,1000*60*5,pendingIntent);
    }
```

In `AlarmManager`,I set the `setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,0,1000*60*5,pendingIntent);`

It will repeating the every 5 minutes duration(1000*60*5 ms = 5minutes)

```
SendLocation.class 
public class SendLocation extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener {
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
         }

  }catch (Exception e){

    }

   Log.i("sendlocation","Every 5 minutes it will appear in Log Console"+latitude+" "+longitude);


  // code for send location to srver
  }
```

Comment: For Better performance switch to fused Location than location manager