# How can I continue running onLocationChanged() in the background even after the app has been closed?

Tags: java, android

I am building an app that silences the user's phone based on their location.  I have been trying to find out how to keep onLocationChanged running even after the app has been closed, but I have not been able to find it.  What can I do here?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Put your onLocationChanged() code inside a service and start the service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478179/background-service-with-location-listener-in-android The selected answer gives a pretty good idea about it.

Comment: will the service keep running even if the user force-closes the app?