# Update google map using location service

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I have a LocationService that gets the user location in the background and sends a broadcast to an activity with the Latitude and Longitude.
It is the code found in the accepted answer to this question [Background service with location listener in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478179/background-service-with-location-listener-in-android)

I created the project with the Google Maps Activity provided by Android Studio. In the MapsActivity I get the broadcast extras like this

```
public class newMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationService.BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
                latitude = extra.getDouble("Latitude");
                longitude = extra.getDouble("Longitude");

                System.out.println("Latitude: "+latitude);
                System.out.println("Longitude: "+longitude);

                LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            }
        }
    }
```

I now want to update the map with the new location but I have no idea how to do this. Is it possible with my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare Broadcast receiver in activity and show marker to current location

```
public BroadcastReceiver locationUpdateReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //show current location marker
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(/*your lat long*/).title("My Location")));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a locationService where you can obtain your current location. Check this example:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("fixedrec", TAG + ">Connected to GoogleApiClient");
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d("fixedrec", TAG+ ">StoppingService");
        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       //plase where you get your locations
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("fixedrec", TAG + "> Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.i("fixedrec", TAG + "> StartLocationUpdates");
    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i("fixedrec", TAG + "> Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
}
```

To broadcast you location across application you can use BroadCastReceiver or EventBus like Otto.
Then just create a  googleMap and add a marker with obtained location to it.

Don't forget yo write locationPermissions inside your manifest file and inside your code if you are dealing with SDK >=23

Also you can study this project. [Fixedrec3](https://github.com/lectricas/fixedrec3)

Everything you need is there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the project. I already have the locationservice and use a Broadcast to send the location to the activity so I don't know what is going wrong. But the project might give me a push in the right direction.

Comment: Try to compile it and see what it is doing. Then you can copy and paste the code inside your project to make things work. Try to avoid using BroadCastReciever - it's complicated. Use otto instead.

Comment: I have to use the BroadcastReveiver. It is a requirement for a school project. But I've got it working now. Thanks for your help. Will definitely take a look at the Fixedrec3 project and otto!