# How to run background operation in android pie or higher?

Tags: android

I want to send coordinates of a location to the server whether the app is closed or running in background. Is there any procedure to run a task in background?

Comment: what you have done till now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478179/background-service-with-location-listener-in-android

Comment: @HaiderSaleem I can't understand what I will use here because service will not work from Android Pie. And I am little confuse about broadcast receiver for location coordinate updating in background. Kindly suggest me the idea for this. Thanks in advance